# Doctype Declaration: XHTML 1.0 vs. XHTML 1.1

Tags: xhtml, doctype

Looking for details on when to use / not-use XHTML 1.0 vs. XHTML 1.1 DTD.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

Reference link: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good reference, also from w3.org, but it doesn't come out and recommend using one over the other.  Depending on what you're trying to do, though, perhaps using the side-by-side comparison will help.

http://www.w3.org/2007/09/dtd-comparison.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use either. Move to html5 which isn't xml at all. The HTML committees seem to be developing a rather regretful attitude toward XML.